# ClearCase mutisite - My SITEB(hub B) crashed

Tags: clearcase

Here is the situation,

I have installed and configured ClearCase Multisite,I did a mkreplica from `SITEA` (`/dev`) to `SITEB` (`/dev`). My import went successfully on `SITEB`. I happen to do few `syncreplicas` too on Both( `SITEA` and `SITEB`). I had both configured on Win2003.

Now the `SITEB` Operation system Win2003 happen with some OS related issues. Now I had recreate an Instance of win2003 and configured CC Multisite on it. Now since everything had been wiped out: I tried to do an `mkreplica` from `SITEA /dev` to `SITEB /dev` (A win2003 new instance)
But, to my surprise, it says `SITEA` has already exported a packed and exits.

I wanted to know if there is a way to wipe out old history of `SITEA for /dev` or do I have to rename `SITEB` to something different? I haven't tried renaming but before I do just need some views over it.

- Amit

Answer (score 0):

I no longer work in a clearcase environment, so this is from memory, but in order to get an exact overview of what is exported or not run the

```
multitool lsepoch
```

command and then try to figure out which epoch numbers that are not up to date (as far as I remember you can request numbers from the remote side with the `-actual` option). If you want SITEA to re-export some things it thinks it already is finished exporting, you have to change the epoch number for the replica you want to import into.

Answer (score 0):

When you consider the [`mkreplica` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_ref.doc/topics/mt_mkreplica.htm), it could be as simple as the destination directory (the directory for use by mkreplica as a temporary workspace) already existing.

You also have [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21238703) which reports why the error, `multitool: Error: Unable to create directory ".../VOB.vbs/s": File exists`, occurs when attempting to import an IBM® Rational® ClearCase MultiSite® replica creation packet using `multitool mkreplica -import`.
It involves unregistering (`unregister`+`rmtag`) the vob created by the first `mkreplica`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are 100% certain that SITEA is most up to date, and the old SITEB is no longer needed. You can do this...

At SITEA

```
cleartool chmaster -all -obsolete_replica replica:SITEB replica:SITEA

cleartool rmreplica replica:SITEB
```

Once the above is done, you are free to re-create SITEB from SITEA as per your usual practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to rename my SITEB to SITEBNEW and did an export it worked. Your idea too seems good i will replicate my issue and try your steps and let you know.

Comment: rename will work if SITEB does not hold any mastership to any object in the VOB, if not the object will get stucked at SITEBNEW forever.